# Default HashMap probing in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

What does Java use as a default probing method for HashMap? Is it Linear? Chaining or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like chaining to me.  Code: [(link)](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm)

```
...
724         /**
725          * Create new entry.
726          */
727         Entry(int h, K k, V v, Entry n) {
728             value = v;
729             next = n;
730             key = k;
731             hash = h;
732         }
...

...
795     void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
796     Entry e = table[bucketIndex];
797         table[bucketIndex] = new Entry(hash, key, value, e);
...
```

That is, grab the entry at bucketIndex, then replace it with a new entry that has as its "next" field the entry that was already there (i.e. chain it).

Comment: It has an extra colon at the end.

Comment: HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap use chains. IdentityHashMap and the implementation of ThreadLocal use linear probing. Other JDK implementations may use different algorithms.